# Change GCC from 4.2.1 to a more recent version on Mac

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, homebrew

Installed GCC 4.7, but my mac currently uses 4.2. How can I switch it?

**Some details which may be helpful:**

OS: Lion 10.7.5

GCC: 4.2.1

Path of GCC 4.2.1: /usr/bin/gcc

Path of GCC 4.7: /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.7

Comment: Change your PATH variable so that the newer GCC is ahead of the old one.

Comment: So as a developer you seriously don't know about `$PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

install GCC 4.8 into Xcode 4.5, Xcode 4.6, Xcode 5.0:

for people who have not install GCC 4.8:

install the new version of home-brew

you can find the method how to install on the Internet

update your brew to the latest version (`$brew update`)

1.`$brew install gcc48 --enable-all-languages`

(may should install mpc, mpfr and gmp through brew, http://solarianprogrammer.com/2013/06/11/compiling-gcc-mac-os-x/)

2.`$brew link gcc48`

3.backup g++,gpp,c++,cpp,c++ in `/usr/bin/`

4.[optional step]:

alias  g++-4.8,gpp-4.8,c++-4.8,cpp-4.8,c++-4.8

from `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.2/bin/g++`

to `/usr/bin/`

**[above 4 steps for the developer who have not install gcc]**

**[@"Donny P": you can skip above 4 steps]**

5.make plugin

1)download  [a plugin of GCC 4.5 for Xcode](https://code.google.com/p/xcode-gcc-plugin/downloads/detail?name=GCC%204.5.xcplugin.zip&can=2&q=)

2)change every "4.5" to "4.8", "4_5" to "4_8", the file names, the file contents,

except "com.apple.compilers.gcc.headers.4_2” in the file `GCC 4.5.xcspec`.

you can remain contents in `English.lproj` unchanged, and delete `Japanese.lproj`.

3)in file `GCC 4.8.xcspec`

(hope you have already change the file name of `GCC 4.5.xcspec` to `GCC 4.8.xcspec`)

change `ExecPath = "...”;`

to `ExecPath = "/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.8"`(@"Donny P": you can change it to "/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.7")

or `ExecPath = "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.2/bin/gcc-4.8"` (for the people who install gcc-4.8 by brew)

or `ExecPath = "/usr/bin/gcc"` (for the people who finished step 4.)

4)delete “-Wshorten-64-to-32” part in file `GCC 4.8.xcspec`

```
{
    Name = "GCC_WARN_64_TO_32_BIT_CONVERSION";
    Type = Boolean;
    DefaultValue = NO;
    CommandLineArgs = {
        YES = (
            "-Wshorten-64-to-32",
        );
        NO = ();
    };
    AppearsAfter = "GCC_WARN_PROTOTYPE_CONVERSION";
    Category = Warnings;
    CommonOption = NO;
    DisplayName = "Implicit Conversion to 32 Bit Type";
    Description = "Warn if a value is implicitly converted from a 64 bit type to a 32 bit type.
    [GCC_WARN_64_TO_32_BIT_CONVERSION, -Wshorten-64-to-32]";
}
```

6.put edited `GCC 4.8.xcplugin` into

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Plugins/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/`

7.reopen Xcode.

Now, the new plugin has already prepared for you. You can see your new GCC compiler plugin in the  "Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C" of "Build Settings" of your project

8.change Build Settings in Xcode project

1)In the `project` and `target` settings in Xcode

change "Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C" to "GCC 4.8"

2)In the `project` settings

delete “CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY" row

Comment: That looks like a lot of hassle - I could not be bothered to do even half of that.

Comment: It is not official. But if you want to use Xcode 4.5+ IDE to work with GCC, you have no choice.

Comment: @trojanfoe Sometimes you should include different headers. And some symbol details are not the same.

Comment: I don't follow; what "different headers" and "symbol details"?  It doesn't look like the OP cares about Xcode anyway, and just needs (user-level) advice about `$PATH`.

Comment: @trojanfoe, in clang, if you include <iostream>, you do not need include <string.h> for using memcpy and <stdin.h> for using int32_t. In GCC, you must include.